# Convert Date/Time to Date/Military Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

How can I convert a `varchar` column in SQL Server 2008 within a table of 1 million+ records containing date/time to the following format: `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`

Example:

```
'Feb 14 2017  3:00PM' converted to '02/14/2017 15:00:00'
'Feb 18 2017 10:03AM' converted to '02/18/2017 10:03:00'
```

The date/time column header = `ACTION_TM`

Please note the double space between the year and time in the first example vs single space of the second. '2017  3:00' vs '2017 10:03'.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

sample  ... varchar(20) for length... and convert to 20 for format or any desired format.

```
select convert(varchar(20),getdate(),20)
```

however in your case you'll have to convert your column into a valid date so should be

```
select convert(varchar(20),cast('Feb 14 2017  3:00PM' as datetime),20)
select convert(varchar(20),cast('Feb 18 2017 10:03AM' as datetime),20)
```

the untidy way of doing it is

```
select convert(varchar(10),cast('Feb 14 2017  3:00PM' as datetime),101) + ' ' +  convert(varchar(112),cast('Feb 14 2017  3:00PM' as datetime),114)
```

Comment: Very close.. This result generated: 2017-02-14 15:00:00, I need: 02/14/2017 15:00:00

Comment: of course, it's meant for you to figure out the correct style

Comment: This seemed to work, I'd like to learn how you came up with this. Where do I find the correct style? In other words, how do I find where you inputted ,101... 112, 114, etc??

Comment: Hi please find the link attached. Style 20 is the 24h format but since your in the US region will need to format the date accordingly unless if you  SQL server is in the US region.